# MySQL How to count columns containing specified column value

Tags: mysql

I have the table xyz

```
ID    day1    day2    day3    day4
1     A         A       P       P
2     A         A       A       P
3     A         A       A       A
4     A         P       P       P
```

I want to be able to query this and return the ID with the number of columns that have A as their value in that row. So the result would look like this:

```
ID    Count
 1     2
 2     3
 3     4
 4     1
```

Comment: How many columns do you have in actual ?

Comment: Any SQL attempts from your side should be posted

Comment: So you want to pass a value (in this case A) as a condition to your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple to accomplish applying `case` to all columns and usmming them up! Try below:

```
select id,
       case day1 when 'A' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day2 when 'A' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day3 when 'A' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day4 when 'A' then 1 else 0 end `CountA`,
       case day1 when 'L' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day2 when 'L' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day3 when 'L' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day4 when 'L' then 1 else 0 end `CountL`,
       case day1 when 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day2 when 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day3 when 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
       case day4 when 'P' then 1 else 0 end `CountP`
from Tbl
```

Comment: Thanks Michal .I Also  the number of columns that have A  L and P  as their value in that row

Comment: @karansharma See updated answer :) Also accept it, if it solved the rpoblem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suppose that I filled all OPs requests, but you are totally right and that's why I used `if` statement :)

Comment: Thanks Michal Its Woks

Comment: @karansharma You have to valid answers, you should accept one of them :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trick you can use involving string concatenation:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(day1, day2, day3, day4)) -
    CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(day1, day2, day3, day4), 'A', '')) AS Count
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

If you want to count other letters as well, just duplicate the logic I have for the letter `A`, e.g. for `L` we can try:

```
CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(day1, day2, day3, day4)) -
CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(day1, day2, day3, day4), 'L', ''))
```

Comment: I think it would be good to place concatenation in subquery and use its results multiple times in outer query. Wouldn't it be more efficient? IMO, it would look cleaner and more concise I guess :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I have no idea what you mean.  The replacement would have to be run separately for each letter, there is no way around this that I can see (short of writing a UDF).

Comment: Well, doing it the way you suggested, you have to invoke concatenation 2 times for each letter. Doing it in a subquery would result in invoking `CONCAT` method once. But I definietely agree that is correct query to get the desired results :) +1

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I see no reason to use a subquery here, whose overhead would likely greatly outweigh any savings you are suggesting.

Comment: Just to be clear: `select char_length(concat(...)) - char_length(concat(...)) from tbl` compared to `select char_length(col) - char_length(replace(col)) from (select concat(...) as col from tbl) as innerTbl`.

Comment: This is trivial, makes the code harder to read, and I wouldn't make that change, except in extreme circumstances.